# Sequelize getting duplicate entry: 'ER_DUP_ENTRY'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm getting this error:

```
code: 'ER_DUP_ENTRY',
     errno: 1062,
     sqlState: '23000',
     index: 0,
     sql: 'INSERT INTO `users` (`id`,`name`,`environment_hash`) VALUES (DEFAULT,\'dasxdsvfbw\',\'2ec13352-89cc-4921-806f-22c1f3bdf29c\');' },
  sql: 'INSERT INTO `users` (`id`,`name`,`environment_hash`) VALUES (DEFAULT,\'dasxdsvfbw\',\'2ec13352-89cc-4921-806f-22c1f3bdf29c\');' }
```

How can I fix this?

This is my models/user.js

```
"use strict";

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var User = sequelize.define("User", {
    id:  { 
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER, 
          autoIncrement: true, 
          primaryKey: true
        },
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    environment_hash: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
          defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4
        }
  }, {
    tableName: 'users',
    underscored: false,
    timestamps: false
  }

  );

  return User;
};
```

And this is my routes.js:

```
app.post('/signup', function(request, response){

        console.log(request.body.email);
        console.log(request.body.password);

        User
        .find({ where: { name: request.body.email } })
            .then(function(err, user) {
                if (!user) {
                        console.log('No user has been found.');

                        User.create({ name: request.body.email }).then(function(user) {
                            // you can now access the newly created task via the variable task
                            console.log('success');
                        }).catch(function(error) {
                            console.log(error);
                        });

                } 
            });



    });
```

Comment: How do you create your initial database schema? Via sequelize, or manually?

Answer (score 1):

First parameter of Sequelize `then` callback is result of query, not error. All errors are handled by `catch` callback. The syntax of Sequelize query:

```
Model.find().then(function(result){
    //handling result
}).catch(function(error){
    //handling error
});
```